# What does Spring Social do when Facebook gives us a new Access Token for a user already connected

Tags: spring-social, spring-social-facebook

When Facebook gives a user a newer updated token and we already have a userconnection record for that user, does a new userconnection record get created or does the userconnection record for that user just get updated with the new token?

Basically, what is happening here is that each device they use creates a new different Facebook token, than what is currently stored in Spring Social's userconnect db table. And it is therefore calling the ConnectionSignUp implementation we have written, which right now creates a new Our App User for our application, instead of seeing that it is the same Facebook user and use the same App internal User in our application.

```
AccountSecurity accountSecurity = accountService.newUserGenerator(newUserName, username, userProfile.getFirstName(),
    userProfile.getLastName(), userProfile.getEmail())
```

Update 12-5-14 4:09 PM PST: It seems that yes, the two different "devices" will get different access tokens. Spring Social will just use the providerid and userproviderid and "see" that they are the same account and not create a new user by calling a ConnectionSignUp execute() method in that case.

However, it seems that Facebook is not sending back the same userproviderid when it should considering it is the exact same app (Flash versus iOS app, but defined as one app in Facebook) and the exact same user account (mine). Facebook should send the same userproviderid.